# Accessing items at deeper levels using children() in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to access a simple button in an unknown nested level of a container.

Using `container.children('button')` allows me to access buttons in the first level, I.E.:

```
<div>
 <button>test</button>
</div>
```

Trying to use the same with the following construct:

```
<div>
 <div>
  <button>test</button>
 </div>
</div>
```

Fails, because the button is not a direct children. I could use `element.children().children('button')` but the depth of the button can change and this feels too strange.

I can also write my own function to iterate though all children to find what I need, but I guess jQuery does already have selectors for this.

So the question is:

How can I access children in an unknown depth using jQuery selectors?

Comment: FYI, *children in an unknown depth* are called descendants. Only direct descendants of an element are called *children*

Answer (score 60, accepted):

How about

```
container.find('button');
```

Answer (score 20):

by using [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)